# Mesh looks 'blotchy' in weight painting

Tags: weight-painting

I'm having a weird problem when I try to weight paint my mesh.  The entire mesh looks 'blotchy' like in the image below:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7a8OU.jpg

This mesh is a model imported from Character creator, which I think may be what's causing the problem as adding a bone to the default blender cube and going to weight painting doesn't cause the effect.  Also, the effect is present immediately after importing into blender, so it's nothing I've done in there.  The thing is, imported meshes from CC looked fine till a few days ago when I swapped my graphics card (5600XT to 6600XT).  I'm thinking it may just be a driver issue as the only drivers available for the new card are non WHQL ones, but thought I'd see if anyone here can suggest another cause and solution.

Thanks all :)

Comment: Are you sure you're looking at one mesh only? (looks like some overlapping)

Comment: That was my first thought too (Z-fighting is it?), but it's definitely just one mesh.  I read another thread on here for a similar thing that the poster solved by recalculating normals, but that doesn't work here either.

Comment: A little more info:  The problem is only present in weight painting (and too a much lesser extent in edit) mode.  Objest mode and sculpt mode look perfectly fine.  Do the two affected modes use some sort of overlay or 'extra skin', for instance to show the different colours of painted areas?  Also, the display mode (solid, material preview etc) doesn't make a difference.